# Scala Sorting With Ex Aqueo

Tags: scala, scala-3

I would like to sort my List[(String, List[Int])] with respect to the second element of the tuple, including ex aqueo elements ( in fp way :) ).

The element w is greater than the element z when:

1. w.sum> z.sum,
2. w.sum == z.sum, but w(0) > z(0),
3. w.sum == z.sum, but w(3) > z(3)

(List always have 3 ints)

For example:
val c =
List(("hah", List(1,1,4)), ("dd", List(4,3,2)), ("aa", List(1,2,3)), ("qw", List(1,2,3)), ("qe", List(2,1,3)), ("w", List(10,0, -9)))

Output (can be in differetnt form of course) - (Place, Tuple, Sum Of Tuple._2):

- First -  ("dd", List(4,3,2)), 9
- Second - ("qe", List(2,1,3)), 6
- Third - ("hah", List(1,1,4)), 6
- Fourth - ("qw", List(1,2,3)), 6
- Fourth - ("aa", List(1,2,3)), 6
- Sixth - ("w", List(10,0,-9)), 1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by using a `case class` rather than bare tuples, and consider using `Vector` rather than `List` for a fixed-sized collection. Then you can add a `compare` method to the `case class` and use `sortWith(_ compare _)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> c.sortBy{ case(_, w) => (w.sum, w(0), w(2)) }.reverse
val res1: List[(String, List[Int])] = List((dd,List(4, 3, 2)), (qe,List(2, 1, 3)), (hah,List(1, 1, 4)), (qw,List(1, 2, 3)), (aa,List(1, 2, 3)), (w,List(10, 0, -9)))
```